# How to cast a ray and detect intersection with a pointcloud using Cesium

Tags: javascript, raytracing, point-clouds, cesiumjs

I'm currently working on a Cesium project that is supposed to cast a ray and find the point where it intersects with a Pointcloud (Cesium3DTileSet).

So far I have not been able to find a method that does this. I did manage to implement scene.pickFromRay and drillPickFromRay as so:

```
//CameraPosition and CameraDirection: [x, y, z]
const { cameraPosition, cameraDirection } = cameraToWorldPoint(rotationQuaternion, translation, geoTransformationMatrix)

const ray = new Cesium.Ray(new Cesium.Cartesian3(cameraPosition[0], cameraPosition[1], cameraPosition[2]), new Cesium.Cartesian3(cameraDirection[0], cameraDirection[1], cameraDirection[2]));
const intersections = viewer.scene.drillPickFromRay(ray, undefined, undefined, 5);
//Always returns an array of one object (Cesium3dTileSet)

return { x: intersections[0].position.x, y: intersections[0].position.y, z: intersections[0].position.z }
```

But the intersections from pickFromRay and drillPickFromRay seem to be happening with the whole CesiumTileSet object, and not the actual points in the pointcloud, which means that it doesn't return the position that I actually need.

Would someone know of different method or way of achieving this?

Comment: It would be nice if you could share some of your inherent code

Comment: Thanks Luca, added some of the code there.

Comment: Chances to hit a single point using a straight line are mathematically close to zero, aren't they?